# How to remove all digits after the last string

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I would like to remove all the digits from the end of: "Car 7 5 8 7 4".
How can I achieve it using regex or other approaches?
I tried following but it only deletes 1 digit:

```
re.sub(r'\s*\d+$', '', text)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\s*\d[\d\s]*$', '', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s41KSM/1).

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\d` - a digit
- `[\d\s]*` - zero or more digits/whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Why the initial `\s*\d`? Optimization, or do you consider it necessary?

Comment: I understand that there must be a digit, only then the replacement should occur.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
text.rstrip(' 0123456789')
```

Comment: Is something wrong with it?